# Can't filter sensitive data with VCR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, replace, vcr

I've got the following in my spec_helper

```
c.filter_sensitive_data("<FILTERED>") { keys['s3_key'] }
c.filter_sensitive_data("<REDACTED>") { keys['s3_secret'] }
```

Yet when I run my spec I find that it creates the following entry in the cassette:

```
Authorization:
- AWS <FILTERED>:this_part_has_not_been_filtered=
```

As you can see there is a part that has not been filtered. I'm not sure if it contains useful information, but I don't want to paste it just incase. I can however say that it doesn't contain my key or my secret. Is it just fluff? Should I care? Is this what normally happens when filtering S3 requests when using the aws-sdk gem? If not then how can I get it to filter all of the authorization data?

Is there a special set of instructions for filtering S3 keys? I really don't want to mess this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like it's safe, if your key isn't there. To be sure, you might use regexp matcher to replace whole string, something like `%r<#{keys['s3_key']:.*?=>`. Bad news: there are no regexp `filter_sensitive_data`. Good news: you can use more low-level methods to implement that yourself.

That's current implementation of `filter_sensitive_data`

```
# @param placeholder [String] The placeholder string.
# @param tag [Symbol] Set this to apply this only to cassettes
#  with a matching tag; otherwise it will apply to every cassette.
# @yield block that determines what string to replace
# @yieldparam interaction [(optional) VCR::HTTPInteraction::HookAware] the HTTP interaction
# @yieldreturn the string to replace
def define_cassette_placeholder(placeholder, tag = nil, &block)
  before_record(tag) do |interaction|
    orig_text = call_block(block, interaction)
    log "before_record: replacing #{orig_text.inspect} with #{placeholder.inspect}"
    interaction.filter!(orig_text, placeholder)
  end

  before_playback(tag) do |interaction|
    orig_text = call_block(block, interaction)
    log "before_playback: replacing #{placeholder.inspect} with #{orig_text.inspect}"
    interaction.filter!(placeholder, orig_text)
  end
end
alias filter_sensitive_data define_cassette_placeholder
```

[Source](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/blob/master/lib/vcr/configuration.rb#L195)

Which leads us to these methods

```
  # Replaces a string in any part of the HTTP interaction (headers, request body,
  # response body, etc) with the given replacement text.
  #
  # @param [#to_s] text the text to replace
  # @param [#to_s] replacement_text the text to put in its place
  def filter!(text, replacement_text)
    text, replacement_text = text.to_s, replacement_text.to_s
    return self if [text, replacement_text].any? { |t| t.empty? }
    filter_object!(self, text, replacement_text)
  end

private

  def filter_object!(object, text, replacement_text)
    if object.respond_to?(:gsub)
      object.gsub!(text, replacement_text) if object.include?(text)
    elsif Hash === object
      filter_hash!(object, text, replacement_text)
    elsif object.respond_to?(:each)
      # This handles nested arrays and structs
      object.each { |o| filter_object!(o, text, replacement_text) }
    end

    object
  end
```

[Source](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/blob/48145a9b234e3554d157408078a156f8511a9393/lib/vcr/structs.rb#L542)

Oh well, we might just try monkey patching this method:

**Somewhere in your spec_helper**:

```
class VCR::HTTPInteraction::HookAware
  def filter!(text, replacement_text)
    replacement_text = replacement_text.to_s unless replacement_text.is_a?(Regexp)
    text = text.to_s
    return self if [text, replacement_text].any? { |t| t.empty? }
    filter_object!(self, text, replacement_text)
  end
end
```

Of course, you can just opt out messing with the deep internals of alien library, and don't feel too paranoid knowing that some random alpha-numeric data is written to cassette near your token (but not including the latter).